# how to send/parse my below json data in android retrofit using GET call

Tags: android

```
public interface iMakeType {
    @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json"})
    @GET("/getmaptable?map_type=Model&brand=(here i need to pass my value dynamically)")
    MakeResponse getMakeTypeData(@Query("map_type")String map_type);
}
```

how can i send my brand value to above call dynamically

> getmaptable?map_type=Model&brand=BMW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public interface iMakeType {
    @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json"})
    @GET("/getmaptable")
    MakeResponse getMakeTypeData(@Query("map_type") String map_type, @Query("brand") String brand);
}
```

Then:

```
yourApi.getMakeTypeData("Model", "BMW").enqueue(...)
```

Comment: Thanks alot dude.!

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of **@QueryMap** from retrofit.

**-** The **@QueryMap** annotation expects a Map with **key-value-pairs** of type **String**. Each key which has a non-null value will be mapped and you can dynamically add your desired query parameters.

```
public interface iMakeType {
    @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json"})
    @GET("/getmaptable")
    MakeResponse getMakeTypeData(@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);
}
```

and implement it like below-

```
 private MakeResponse makeType() {  
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("map_type", "Model");
    data.put("brand", "BMW");


    MakeResponse call = api.getMakeTypeData(data);
    call.enqueue(…);

}
```

I hope, this will help you to add **@Query Param** Dynamically !